# Undefined global var

Tags: go, undefined, identifier

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
)

var a = []byte{0, 0}

var b, c []byte

func gens(n int) ([]byte, error) {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    _, err := rand.Read(b)
    // Note that err == nil only if we read len(b) bytes.
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return b, nil
}

func main() {
    key, _ := gens(30)

    fmt.Printf("len %d key \n%x\n", len(key), key)
    for s := 1; s <= len(key); s++ {
        b := make([]byte, len(key))
        b = key[s:]
        c = key[:s]

        fmt.Printf("%d %x %x\n", s, b, c)
        // b = append(b, с...)
        // fmt.Printf("len %d key %x\n",len(d), d)
    }
}
```

Hello everybody!
I want to create a function for cyclic rotation of an array of bytes, I take a simple function byte generator, and then try to rotate them byte-by-bye when I print - everything looks fine, but when I try to make an append(commented out 2 lines), I get Undefined с:

**# command-line-arguments
./prepareKey.go:33:17: undefined: с**

What's wrong!?? Forgive me if it was already there, poke me, I'm in a stupor from this! var c this global...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the variable name and the identifier you use in `append` *visually look the same*, **but they are different characters!**

If you print their bytes :

```
fmt.Println([]byte("c")) // var b, c []byte
fmt.Println([]byte("с")) // b = append(b, с...)
```

Output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0L0Sxg_5qG4)):

```
[99]
[209 129]
```

**Fix:** Delete that `'c'` lookalike, and write a "normal" `'c'` character.

Once you do it, the app compiles and runs fine. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RCaVdx0Vjbu).

Comment: Ha, it's a lowercase cyrillic "s"! https://www.codetable.net/hex/441 Good find.

Comment: indeed, I renamed the variable and it worked ...
maybe I printed it on a different layout, but I honestly don't understand what happened, THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing an equals sign:

```
var b, c = []byte
```